# Html tags in Jenkins log

Tags: html, logging, jenkins, formatting

All!

For one of our projects we are using Jenkins Continuous Integration system. The build process is pretty heavy and produce a lot of different logs. To make logs easier to read I decided to create a Jenkins plugin which will reformat logs and makes them more readable. For this purpose I created an extension for ConsoleLogFilter. The only one overridden method there looks now like this:

```
public OutputStream decorateLogger(AbstractBuild abstractBuild, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    FilterOutputStream filter = new FilterOutputStream(outputStream) {
           private String currentLogMessage = "";
           @Override
           public void write( int data ) throws IOException {
               switch (data) {
                   case '\n':
                       if (currentLogMessage.startsWith("+")) {
                           currentLogMessage = "<span style='color: darkgray; font-size: 10pt'>" + currentLogMessage + "</span>";
                       }
                       currentLogMessage += Character.toString ((char) data);
                       out.write( currentLogMessage.getBytes() );
                       System.out.println(currentLogMessage);
                       currentLogMessage = "";
                       break;
                   default:
                       currentLogMessage += Character.toString ((char) data);
                       break;
               }
           }
       };

    return filter;
}
```

The problem appeared very tricky. This decorator doing it's job pretty well and in Jenkins log I see that messages are wrapped with HTML-span correctly (result of System.out.println(...)). It looks like this:

```
<span style='color: darkgray; font-size: 10pt'>+ some log content</span>
<span style='color: darkgray; font-size: 10pt'>+ some log content</span>
<span style='color: darkgray; font-size: 10pt'>+ some log content</span>
```

But when it comes to the browser it appears that all opening tag symbols like < are replaced with &lt; and browser can't parse this formatting correctly

```
&lt;span style='color: darkgray; font-size: 10pt'>+ some log content&lt;/span>
&lt;span style='color: darkgray; font-size: 10pt'>+ some log content&lt;/span>
&lt;span style='color: darkgray; font-size: 10pt'>+ some log content&lt;/span>
```

Do anyone saw this problem? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Seems like an encoding problem,Make sure your file's encoding is correct

Comment: It seems that this is a known issue of Jenkins
[JENKINS-17564 - "<a href" at test result file is converted to "&lt;a href" at TestNG results screen](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17564)

And according to the comments there, it'll be fixed in v 1.3

Comment: Discard my previous comment, it is about this problem in test results, but my problem is in the build log